# Does this violate the 'leftmost longest' principle?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex to recognize a single line of text, with underscore ( _ ) recognized as a line continuation character.  For example, "foo_\nbar" should be considered a single line, because the "foo" ends in an underscore.  I am trying:

```
$txt = "foo_\nbar";
print "$&\n" if $txt =~ /.*(_\n.*)*/;
```

However, this prints only:

```
foo_
```

This seems to violate the "leftmost longest" rule for Perl regexes!

Interestingly, if I remove the last star (*) in the regex, i.e.:

```
$txt = "foo_\nbar";
print "$&\n" if $txt =~ /.*(_\n.*)/;
```

it **does** print:

```
foo_
bar
```

But I need the star to recognize "0 or more" continuations!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with this regex though? What would you like to do with it?

Comment: "recognize a single line of text, with underscore ( _ ) recognized as a line continuation character"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why is this happening was explained by @ysth. To fix it you may use the following regex:

```
/([^_\n]|_.)*/s
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl doesn't do "leftmost longest"; instead, each regex feature has a well-defined way of acting.  Your initial * will match as many times as possible, so long as the rest of the regex can match at all.  To prevent it from swallowing the _, do something like:

```
/(.*(?!(?<=_)\n)_\n)*.*/
```

Comment: Not really:  `.*` match non-newlines, `(?!` but don't end with, `(?<=_)` something preceded by a `_`, `\n` that is a newline `)*` repeated for as many lines as possible `.*` and get the following line too

Comment: ZyX's is much nicer but a less literal translation of the defined problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic flavors of regular expression designs:

POSIX defines the leftmost-longest flavor.  For example: changing any "a|b" to "b|a" does nothing to the full match.

PERL defines the left-biased flavor. Each "a|b" checks the left-branch "a" and if this can match then "b" is never checked.  Thus "a|b" is rarely the same as "b|a".  Here a* is like ()|a|aa|aaa|aaaa|...